# Why is compression not working in servicestack

Tags: servicestack

I'm having trouble getting compression to work with ServiceStack. I return `.ToOptimizedResult` from my server, and I get a log entry that tells my that the header is added:

```cs
ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Extensions.HttpResponseExtensions: 
DEBUG: Setting Custom HTTP Header: Content-Encoding: deflate
```

However the content returned is not compressed. I've checked using both Fiddler and Network inspector in Chrome.

Comment: You can have IIS do all the compression work if you are running within IIS7. Are you in IIS7?

Comment: @Henk I'm on IIS 7 and compression was enabled on static content. I enabled dynamic content as well, but that didn't help. Is this why SS is not working? Because can't enable compression?

Comment: It seems that IIS removes the Content-Encoding from the response after SS has processed it, and decompresses the response. From what I can find, comressed output has to be written to the HttpResponse.Filter stream, but I get an exception if I write to it.
Another bug is that Response.ContentType is not set when SS is compressing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to all
It seems that maybe my antivirus (BitDefender) decompresses the data to scan for virus, even though I disabled the AV. When testing on other computers the output is compressed.